# how to generate unique number per day in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have to implement inventory system. in this case I am adding the batch number for finding the expire date each product using batch number. It will generate per day for one unique number.

```
public string Number { get; set; } =
    DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") +"-"+
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + "#BN";
```

Comment: so what's wrong with your code? if it's executed once a day, the `yyyyMMdd` itself should be unique as long as your system datetime is kept correct.

Comment: I am asking about I am adding the products to inventory today. Then todays all products have one unique batch number for  all products.                                                                               Example: 2021/03/15   ==>  20210315-001#BN                                                                                                 
                2021/03/15   ==>  20210315-001#BN                                                                                                
                2021/03/16   ==>  20210316-002#BN    need like this

Comment: `yyyyMMdd` should be unique for the batch of the day, ***any other combined text*** (suffix or prefix) can be unique by product (or anything) to make the whole code unique by day. Even you can use the product id to combine with the daily code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string QuestionNumber { get; set; } =
  DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" +
  Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + "#Q";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.